# simple XML load file , how can i load xml file once in a 5 minute

Tags: php, xml, get, load

```
$connect_web = simplexml_load_file('http://www.currency.com/currencies/today.xml');
$usd_buying = $connect_web->Currency[0]->BanknoteBuying;
$usd_selling = $connect_web->Currency[0]->BanknoteSelling;
```

currency.php

i get the currency from outsource by xml.
and use this on my main page,

```
<?php
require_once('currency.php');
global $usd_buying ;
global $usd_selling ; 
?>
```

On my main page there is a search box which is triggered key up with every key pressed.
I get data from database and use the currency for every time key pressed.
So every time key pressed , page get the xml data from out source .
I want to get xml data once in a 5 min. not every time key triggered.
Is there any solution for this , like session?or anything else.

```
function view_record()
{
    $("#search").keyup(function()
    {
    var searchword = $(this).val();
    
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'viewdata.php',
            method: 'post',
           data:{searchword:searchword},
           dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data)
            {
              if(data.status=='success')
                { $('#table').html(data.html);
```

}

Comment: Caching. Store the values in Database and use them from there. Create a cronjob running each 5 minutes to refresh the XML data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript setInterval function. ( Detail of this function : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp )

Sample js for your code ;

```
function getCurrency(){ //ajax request your currency.php and get data //print data in target div via js } 
setInterval(getCurrency,300000);  //300000 = 5 min (60*5*1000 microseconds) , every 5 minute working getCurrency function
```